# How to init angular datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plugins, datepicker

I am using angular datepicker plugin
https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker

and i don`t understand what i have to do for init it.
I have created

```
<input type="datetime" class="form-control" date-picker ng-model="user.birthDate" view="date" auto-close="true">
```

I tried the same code with both input and div instead of input, but nothing happens ( by the way angular.js, moment.js angular-datepicker.js were imported as well ).

Nothing occurres when i click on input or div
What is missing in my code?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your code, more than just one line of html perhaps in a codepen or plunker?

Comment: @SeanLarkin this code from large project(with backend part), I can`t provide it whole

Comment: Sure but one line of html doesn't show enough to solve your answer. For example. Are you including the dependancies correctly into your project, is the module registered in your application module correctly, etc. 

Putting a proof of concept into a codepen or plunker will help us see what you may be doing wrong.